# Decimal check on OnKeyUp event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I have couple of text boxes. In those text boxes I need to check few types.

1. Allow only Numbers and Decimals

Example: 123.2323  //not allowed any characters

2. Allow only 2 numbers after decimal

Example: 123.23  //not allowed any characters and only allowed 2 digits after decimal

3. Allow only 1 number after decimal

Example: 123.2  //not allowed any characters and only allowed 1 digits after decimal

I have to check these validation in `OnKeyPress` event in text boxes.

If possible need all three methods.

Please help me on this.

Comment: What you are looking for is some regular expressions experts... :P

Comment: You need to do a better job describing what you want. You might want to use regex perhaps ... unless this needs to be blazing fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Regular expressions](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) and [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) are your friends here.

Also, something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) might help with [validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can try this jquery [plugin](http://decorplanit.com/plugin/) for formatting numbers.

You can set how many decimal places you want. It has nice documentation so it is easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the need for this to happen on the KeyUp event, you'll need to use JavaScript.  [Here's](http://javascript.internet.com/forms/validate-numeric-only.html) a script for validating numeric only that you can modify for your needs.